# Varnish Vcl for multiple incoming and outgoing port connections

Tags: varnish, haproxy, varnish-vcl

Since a little while I am using Varnish Cache solutions and as long as the configuration was more or less the same as it was after the installation everything worked out very well.

But now I like to do a little bit more with Varnish. Currently I am using the following setup for my servers :

Visitors -> CloudFlare -> HaProxy -> Varnish (separate servers) -> Apache2 Content.

What I like to know is how am I able to make the right vcl script to accept let's say an incoming request from ip A on port B and redirect this to ip C on port D. (And this more than once.)

Example :

Default.Varnish works well like this:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :8085,:8087 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,768m"
```

But now about the Varnish.Default :

```
backend default_1 { .host = "11.22.333.444"; .port = "8885"; }
backend default_2 { .host = "11.22.333.444"; .port = "8887"; }
```

And I tried something like this :

```
sub vcl_recv {
 if (server.port == 8885) { set req.backend = default_1; }
 if (server.port == 8887) { set req.backend = default_2; }
}
```

(Please be aware of the fact that both requests are going to the
same outgoing server. Only the port is different!)

Someone who knows enough from Varnish already knows what I want I guess. I just like to use Varnish to proxy separate 'channels' based on different ports.

Comment: Try setting `req.backend_hint` instead of `req.backend`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check Varnish bind port, not backend port

```
sub vcl_recv {
 if (server.port == 8085) { set req.backend = default_1; }
 if (server.port == 8087) { set req.backend = default_2; }
}
```

Comment: Getting this answer while restarting Varnish :

 * Checking syntax varnishd
   ...fail!
Message from VCC-compiler:
Symbol not found: 'server.port' (expected type BOOL):
('input' Line 20 Pos 6)
 if (server.port == 8085) { set req.backend = default_1; }
-----###########------------------------------------------

Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2

Comment: Probably this has something to do with it (I forgot to mention I am using version 4 of Varnish.) :

client.port, and server.port replaced by respectively std.port(client.ip) and std.port(server.ip)
client.ip and server.ip are now proper datatypes, which renders as an IP address by default. You need to use the std.port() function to get the port number.

Found in this document : https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/whats-new/upgrading.html

Comment: I un-installed version 4 of Varnish and installed 3.0 just to get this routine running. Later on we hopefully find a way to do the same with version 4.

So for now I hope I did the right thing by accepting your answer as the solution Mr. Ghloogh.